# How can I get a record who has two exact relation records in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am building a messaging system in Laravel. 
Right now I have Threads, Participants and Messages tables.

Relation between threads and participants is many-to-many (one thread can have 2 participants, participants can have many threads). 
I need a way to display last messages between two participants. 
So the question is - how can I query a database, to find if there is a Thread which has a two exact participants?